# How can I query model objects with async Sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I'm trying the new asyncio features Sqlalchemy offers. I'm finding it quite frustrating. Before I could use

```py
session.query(
  objects.User,
).filter(...)
```

to query a user objects with all of its fields populated.

With asyncio I have to do

```
result await db.execute(
  sqlalchemy.select(objects.User).filter(...)
)
result.all()
```

`result.all()` returns `Row` objects which appear to be just a list of lists with all the values of the model in no particular order. I can get at the data using protected attributes like `list(row)[0]._mapping['country_id']`. The whole thing just feels very cumbersome and not as clean as when I got model objects back. Is there any way to get models in asyncio land?

I don't want to submit a code review where I'm doing `object._mapping['field_name']` everywhere and I'll have a hard time selling this to my team.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? And how did you do that? It would be extremely useful if you published an answer to this question. I use the function scalar().

Comment: @CrazyTheory Yeah, you have to use `.scalars().all()` so like `(await session.execute(sqlalchemy.select(model))).scalars().all()`